# How To Code Loading Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, loading

How do programmers code proper loading screens? 
This is how I envision the code behind a loading screen, but I was wondering if there is a better way than just a bunch of conditional statements:

```
loading = 0
def load(percent):
    while percent <= 100:
        if percent == 0:
            foo.loadthing() # Just an example function
            percent += 10
        else if percent == 10:
            foo.loadthing()
            percent += 10

        ...

        else if percent == 100:
            foo.loadthing()
load(loading);
```

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python, but if there's a better way coding loading screens without using modules from different languages, I probably be able to convert it to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got it backward. I wouldn't code a loading screen based from a loading screen.

Not sure about your language i hope you'll understand my c# prototype

```
//Gui thread
var screen = LoadingScreen.Show();
await doWork(); //<- c# way to make doWork happen on 2nd thread and continue after the thread has been finished.
screen.Hide();

//somewhere else
async void doWork() {
   for(int i = 0; i < filesToLoad; ++i) {
      LoadFile(i);
      LoadingScreen.SetPercentage = 100.0 * i / filesToLoad;
   }
}
```

what you see happening here is 2 threads. 1 thread (gui) that shows the loadingscreen for as long as the 2nd thread is doing work. This 2nd thread will send updates to the loading screen saying 'hey i did some more work, please update'

**Update** Ah now i see you're using python. My idea should still stand though. You should loop over the work you need to be doing and then calculate the updates from there.

Comment: Hey thanks, I think I got the concept: program multiple threads, one task loads stuff and the other displays. The only thing I'm confused is this line of code or is this just a c# thing: screen.Hide()?

Comment: screen.Hide() is prototype close the loadingscreen and continue with the rest of your program. Loadingscreens are often implemented kind of like modal dialogs (without buttons) after which you need to close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

How to create a loading screen using the sys module:
It may not look like it, but this should definitely work..

```
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
for i in range(101):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("[%-10s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 1*i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
import time
import replit
from random import randint
percent = 0
for i in range(100):
    replit.clear()
    percent +=1
    print("""
LOADING SCREEN
Status: loading

%"""+ str(percent)
         )
    time.sleep(randint(1,2))
    
print("Loading complete!\n")
print("Now...")
time.sleep(2)
print("What you have been waiting for...")
time.sleep(2)
print("Nothing")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).